# Qual a diferença entre ", " e "+" no Python?

Tags: python, string, operadores

Num código

```
mensagem = "ola "
nome = input("Diga seu nome ")
print (mensagem + nome )
```

```
mensagem = "ola"
nome = input("Diga seu nome ")
print (mensagem , nome )
```

Os dois fazem a mesma função , com a diferença que usando o sinal `+` , tenho que dar um espaço. Eu sei que `+` concatena, mas essa é a única diferença?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o @Maniero explicou, a forma de funcionar é **completamente diferente**, apesar de fazer a mesma coisa(nesse caso), e eu gostaria de adicionar umas informações não mencionadas por ele.

A função print tem o parâmetro `sep=' '`, que é um caractere de separação(por padrão, é um espaço em branco). Então, se você passa mais de um objeto pra imprimir(string, int, etc), ele intercala os objetos com o caractere de separação. Por exemplo:

```
print('oi','MrLexotan')
```

retorna

```
>>>oi MrLexotan
```

porém

```
print('oi', 'MrLexotan', sep='@')
```

retorna

```
>>>oi@MrLexotan
```

e se vc fizer

```
print('oi', 'MrLexotan','tudo', 'bem','?', sep='@')
```

retorna

```
>>>oi@MrLexotan@tudo@bem@?
```

**Qual a vantagem que se tem com o `sep`?**

A vantagem é: no futuro, é possivel se deparar com uma situaçao em que vc não sabe o numero de objetos pra passar na função print, então é impossivel vc dar espaço individualmente entre eles(como vc fez no caso do mensagem + nome. Vc definir um separador acaba com esse problema.

Espero que tenha entendido. Apesar de ter achado o amigo Maniero um pouco impaciente em sua resposta, tentei explicar da maneira mais didática possivel. As linguagens de programação são feitas por seres humanos, que se depararam com problemas, e por isso criaram essas soluções. Dificilmente duas coisas vão ter a mesma função.

Não fique desencorajado por gente que domina a área há anos e te acusa de estar aprendendo errado. Aprender da maneira que você pode é melhor do que desistir. Programação tb é aprender a aprender, e isso se pega com a prática.

Abraços e boa sorte na jornada pelo mundo da tecnologia :)

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado . Eu entendo o ponto de vista dele , e tendo a concordar parcialmente , eu sinto que poderia estar aprendendo mais, conforme vou estudando, mais duvidas aparecem , mas não encontro um curso ou livro em português, que consigam sanar minhas duvidas, eu sei que o inglês é de suma importância na programação, estou estudando, mas no nível que estou, tentar aprender não é uma opção, muita coisa ficaria de fora. Recomenda algum material em ingles ?

Comment: Eu achei sua resposta impaciente com a minha reposta. Se acho isso errado não faça você a mesma coisa que está criticando. A crítica é válida quando não se comete ela.

Comment: Tenha em mente que inglês não é um conteudo fixo. Igual no português, você aprende termos específicos a certas áreas quando entra em contato com elas. No nivel básico vc consegue cursos ainda em portugues(Na udemy tem alguns pagos, mas se não quiser gastar, te recomendo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YO58tXerKDc&list=PLUukMN0DTKCtbzhbYe2jdF4cr8MOWClXc (é excelente).

Comment: Da mesma forma, se vc seguir na área, é inevitável vc aprender o básico. COnforme vc avança, os melhores conteúdos vão estar em inglês,as vezes sendo até inexistente a versão em portugues

Answer (score 3):

De fato, o operador `+` nesse contexto faz a concatenação de textos de forma simples, o que significa que gerará um outro objeto que conterá o conteúdo dos dois objetos usados com o operador, e esse objeto será usado onde quer que seja necessário, por exemplo pode ser um argumento para passar para uma função como foi usado no primeiro código. A concatenação por acaso está sendo composta com a função `print()`.

O operador `,` nada tem a ver com isso, ele serve para separar elementos em uma lista em alguns contextos, e a forma exata varia de acordo com o contexto.

A função `print()` aceita diversos argumentos. De 0 a virtualmente ilimitados podem ser usados porque é como se fosse passar um *array*. Como você separa cada argumento a ser passado para uma função? Simples, isso é uma lista de argumentos, separa com a vírgula.

Então no segundo código está chamando a função passando dois argumentos para a função `print()`. Por acaso quem a escreveu determinou que essa função imprimiria os argumentos que vem depois do primeiro com um espaço em branco de separação. Nesse contexto acontece isso, mas é o que o `print()` faz, não serve para outras situações na linguagem.

Pode parecer que o resultado é quase o mesmo, mas o que está acontecendo é totalmente diferente. Não é criado um objeto novo para isso, portanto é mais eficiente.

Na verdade é mais complicado do que está imaginando. Lamento te informar, mas parece estar aprendendo de uma forma que não dá a noção de como realmente as coisas funcionam no código, então terá dificuldade pra sempre se não mudar o jeito de aprender.

Quando aprende as causas e consequências pode ir construindo código mais avançados em cada passo que dá e programar é isso, entender cada conceito e ir combinando-os corretamente para produzir o melhor resultado. Quando aprender só os resultados só consegue fazer o que já viu alguém fazendo antes, e isso não é programar.

Vou dar um exemplo que parece bobo. Por que deu espaço antes da abertura de parênteses em uma função e não na outra? Os dois funcionam. Mas entender porque dá o espaço ou porque é melhor sem o espaço faz diferença para entender de fato o que é o código, porque está fazendo aquilo. Funciona fazer aleatoriamente como está no código, mas sem pensar no que está escrevendo, verá que há um motivo para não usar espaço ali e dará o primeiro passo para ter mais consciência sobre tudo o que escreve e entender cada detalhe do código, até os que não parecem importantes, mas que tem um significado.

Isso é o que diferencia quem é novato por um tempo e quem é novato pela vida toda. Mas claro que todo mundo pode escolher o caminho que achar melhor, eu dei a dica porque pareceu que quer aprender o certo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Pois é me sinto exatamente assim .Estou estudando vendo os vídeos da alura e lendo um livro chamado "Curso intensivo de Python", os vídeos se baseiam em pegar um projeto, e te ensinar como fazer, mas não existe vídeos específicos sobre cada função, muitas coisas são passadas de forma muito rápida, o livro apresenta muitas coisas, mas sem muito aprofundamento , no final vou fazer 3 projetos, o mais interessante é um jogo. Você sabe de algum curso ou livro, que posso me aprofundar? tenho uma deficiência em ingles ( estudo todos os dias, em breve será resolvido), em ingles não é uma possibilidade

Comment: Isso é o que os cursos fazem, criam uma ilusão que você está aprendendo porque vê o resultado. Esses cursos estão no negócio de criar felicidade e não preparar as pessoas para serem profissionais. Por isso vendem tanto. E não estou falando de um específico, falo no geral, não sei avaliar individualmente nenhum deles. Mas é um pouco problema das pessoas também. Elas acreditam que podem aprender de forma simples e rápida, os cursos entregam o que elas querem. Tem que pegar muito conteúdo, alguns chatos, tem que olhar pra coisas que parecem irrelevantes para um leigo, mas não são.